# im trying to find the x position of the mouse cursor

Tags: pygame, mouse

I'm making a game using python's pygame module and am trying a new method where a weapon will rotate based on the mouse's position, and I'm trying to find a point that would form a right angle between the center of the player's cube and the mouse's x position
this is the code:

point_a = (mouse.get_pos(), player_cube.centery)

if I wanted to find only the x position of 'mouse.get_pos()', how would I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) states that the function returns the x and y values ​​you want.

```
pos = mouse.get_pos()
x = pos[0]
y = pos[1]

# or just one line
x, y = mouse.get_pos();
```

Answer (score 0):

mouse.get_pos()[0] - mouse.get_pos() returns a tuple (list)
alternatively you could put
pos = mouse.get_pos()
x = pos[0]